# Can I force SignalR to use the same 5-tuple connection while handshaking?

Tags: azure, websocket, signalr, owin

Scenario:

I have a cloud service (more than 1 instance) sitting in front of Azure Load Balancer (LB). I'm OWIN self-hosting a SignalR endpoint. As far as I know, SignalR handshake consists of 3 HTTP Get-Reponses (connect, negotiate, start).

The problem I'm having is that the LB is routing them to different machines, so the handshake fails.

I'm guessing I'm not the first who ran into this issue, so is there a simple solution? (preferably without introducing 3rd party).

I was thinking of forcing the HTTP client to use the same tuple (client ip, client port) and pray that the LB is doing the same (maps the 5 tuple to a single machine until the sessions ends)

Comment: If you are not using scaleout you need to make sure that the clients are not jumping servers. If you are using scaleout you need to make sure that machine keys on all the servers are the same.

Comment: What was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very unfamiliar with SignalR, but if changing the Load Balancer hashing mode to 3-tuple (Source IP, Destination IP, Protocol) or 2-tuple (Source IP, Destination IP) gets around it, well, you could do that.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-load-balancer-new-distribution-mode/

Service Definition (.csdef):

```xml
<WorkerRole name="worker-role-name" vmsize="worker-role-size">
  <Endpoints>
    <InputEndpoint name="input-endpoint-name" ... loadBalancerDistribution="sourceIP" />
  </Endpoints>
</WorkerRole>
```

> The value of `loadBalancerDistribution` can be **sourceIP** for **2-tuple** affinity, **sourceIPProtocol** for **3-tuple** affinity or **none** (for no affinity. i.e. **5-tuple**)